# redirect / to /?C=N;O=A

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to be able to use

```
IndexOrderDefault Descending Date
```

for all of my sub-folders, but I want to the first page to be sorted by name (A-Z)

I read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13199268/htaccess-directive-for-subfolders but I do not seem to be able to use `<Directory>` in .htaccess

My next thought was that perhaps I could use `mod_rewrite` to 
redirect people from  http://iusethis.tjluoma.com/  to http://iusethis.tjluoma.com/?C=N;O=A

But so far I have not been able to figure out how to do this.

*(In case it isn't blatantly obvious, I am a complete newbie at this and may be missing something obvious.)*

Answer (score 1):

An `.htaccess` file has an implied `<Directory>` that contains the `.htaccess` file.  An `.htaccess` file is a configuration that applies to the directory it is found in.  Just directly place the options that you would use in a `<Directory>` container in the `.htaccess` file.  You don't need to add the `<Directory>`.